# Why is string.Length not working on text.Substring?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, substring

I'm trying to get the string after the given word. Below is the code.

```
private static string GetStringAfterWord(string text, int position)
    {
        if (text.Length - 1 < position || text[position] == ' ') return null;

        int start = position;
        int end = position;

        while (end < text.Length - 1 )   
        end++;

        return text.Substring(start, end);

    }
```

This code always give me this error:  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Isn't the string.Length return the number of total characters and why is always out of range. Am i doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.SubString`'s second argument is the length of the substring.

In your example, you're saying `grab the string starting at <start> and is <end> characters long`. If `start` is 2 and the length of the string is 11, then `end` would be 10.. which if added together makes 12 (10+2=12.. while the length of the string is 11).

You need this:

```
return text.Substring(start, end - start);
```

..and this:

```
while (end < text.Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if (text.Length - 1 < position || position < 0 || text[position] == ' ')
```

And replace

```
 while (end < text.Length - 1 )   
    end++;
```

with

```
 end = text.Length - start;
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument of `Substring()` method is not an index, it's a length.